# redirect header function in php script not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, header

I am using local host to host this test site and in one of my java-script files i created an ajax request to a php script

```
if(hIF == "true"){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "log_in/login.php",
        data: {name: userName, pwd: password},
        success: function(response){

          if(response=="true")
          {
             changeColor('#add_err', 'rColWet', 'gColor');
             $("#add_err").text("Login Successfull");
             $('#clEx').delay("slow").click();
             //window.location = "profile/dashboard.php";
          }
          else if(response=="false")
          {
               changeColor('#add_err', 'gColor', 'rColWet');
             $("#add_err").text("Login Failed");
          }else {
             $("#add_err").text(" Abnormal response from server");
             alert(response);
             }
        }
    });
```

and in a section of my PHP script, i have a call to a function that is expected to redirect the user to a different page if the preceding condition is true.

```
if($num_row >=1){
move_to();
}
else{
echo 'false';
}
```

Here is the function which is located at the top of the php script.

```
function move_to(){
header('location:..//profile//dashboard.php?');
exit;
}
```

Everything seems to be in correct order, but when i run the code it does not redirect me to the page specified in the move_to function, but instead sends the content of the php script (i.e that is the file i expect to be redirected to) back to the ajax call.

I would be comfortable with using "window.location = "" for redirecting to a different page, as this worked perfectly when i used it, but i would like to see this header method for redirecting work (i.e using the header function to redirect). I also want to know why google does not recommend using "window.location" for redirecting and what are the downsides to using this method (i.e using window.location for redirecting). Thank youuu :)

Comment: If you want the ajax call to redirect the page that it originates from, it might be more benefical if, rather than making php do the redirect, return a response to the request of something like `{ status: 301, location: 'newUrl' }` and then have your success of the ajax evaluate if the status is a 200 or not.  If it is a 301, use the location for your window.location.href command.

Comment: No i want to redirect to a new page from the php script, I removed the section for evaluating the response from the php file (i.e the section for success in the ajax call, please ignore that section in the code snippet i pasted) but it did not redirect as expected.

Comment: "instead sends the content of the php script (i.e that is the file i expect to be redirected to) back to the ajax call" — Well yes. A redirect means "What you asked for is over there" not "I assume you are using a web browser, and no matter what you wanted to do with the data you asked for, you should navigate to an entirely new page instead".

Answer (score 0):

Why are you creating a function for redirecting....Anyway, you can still use window.location from php as per code below

```
echo "<script>window.location='..//profile//dashboard.php'</script>";
```

make sure that the URL is correct otherwise use the full URL link Path for testing Eg. **http://localhost/profile//dashboard.php**

In a nutshell try this

```
if($num_row >=1){
move_to();
header("Location:../profile//dashboard.php");
//or

 echo "<script>window.location='..//profile//dashboard.php'</script>";
}
else{
echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: okay. you were trying to redirect user as the user logs in right.. and are you sure the redirecting url is okay

Comment: i will post in a minute or two

Comment: If you can post the entire code php I can try to assist you further and beside I use PDO for mysql Interaction so if you post the code in mysqli, just have in mind that I can  re-write to PDO. I work faster with PDO. Thanks

Comment: Thanks man .... I tried the using the redirect header function on a separate form that posted data directly to a php script, it worked ... Probably, the reason its not working is because i'm using ajax to make the request as it requires a response to complete that post (just as in my case it sends my case it sends the content of the php script)....

Comment: I created a hidden form field in my document and filled it with the post details required by the target location (i.e. That is the php script i wanted to redirect to with the redirect location header function) and used javascript to click on the submit button in this form to post the data to the location specified in the action attribute in this hidden form field .... Not too elegant a solution, but worked perfectly ..........

Comment: Is there a way to restrict an ajax call from waiting for a response to a script it posted data so it doesn't hinder any subsequent action/event made by that script (for example in my case -- changing the location) ..... (Although, i know that an ajax call is sought of a third party merchant man whose sole function is to perform a transaction between two entities and not to a single well favoured entity)... I'm interested in knowing how this can be done if it is possible.. Thank you

Comment: Also, is it a good practise to use Ajax for login and registration or is it best to just make the login request from your form through your php script?